# How to copy hashset and hashmap, and does the Java use pointers?

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, copy, hashset

I have two questions:
First:
I have a function which returns a HashMap. To read the returned value, I write it like this:

```
    HashMap<Integer,String> hs=my_func2();
```

I do the same if the function returns a HashSet.

```
    HashSet<Integer> hs=my_func();
```

I wanted to know if in this way the returned value is copied into hs, or I should write a deep copy for it or I should write it like this: 
        HashSet hs=new HashSet(my_func());
        HashMap hm=new HashMap(my_func2());

Second quesion:
I make a matrix by calling make_matrix_funciton. matrix woule be a 2-dimensional array containing:
[0 1 1
 0 0 0
 0 0 0]
Then I give this matrix to sort_vec, and in this function the elements of matrix change. I think java is not pointer based, so when I come out of sort_vec, matrix should be as it had been. But, it has changed! It is
[0 0 0
 0 0 0
 1 1 0]
which shows the changes that had been applied to it inside the sort_vec function. Is it normal and if yes, what should I do to prevent it. The code below is compilable.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int matrix[][]=new int[3][3];
        matrix=make_matrix("011000000");
        int indexes[]={2,1,0};
        int[][] mat=sort_vec(3,matrix,indexes);
    }

    private static int[][] sort_vec(int motifsize,int [][]mat,int[] indexes)
    {
        int[] main_index={0,1,2};

        int l=indexes.length;
        for (Integer i=0;i<l;i++)
            if(indexes[i]!=main_index[i])
            {
                int j=indexes[i];
                int k=main_index[i+1];
                for(;k<l;k++)
                    if(indexes[k]==main_index[i])
                        break;

                indexes[k]=j;
                mat=exchange(motifsize,mat,j,main_index[i]);
            }
        return mat;
    }
    private static int[][] exchange(int motifsize,int [][]matrix,int x,int y)
    {
        int temp;

        for(int i=0;i<motifsize;i++)
        {   
            temp=matrix[i][x];
            matrix[i][x]=matrix[i][y];
            matrix[i][y]=temp;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<motifsize;i++)
        {   
            temp=matrix[x][i];
            matrix[x][i]=matrix[y][i];
            matrix[y][i]=temp;
        }

        return matrix;
    }
    private static int[][] make_matrix(String id)
    {
        int matrix[][]=new int[3][3];
        int c=0;
        for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
            for(int y=0;y<3;y++)
            {
                if(id.charAt(c)=='1' || id.charAt(c)=='5')
                    matrix[x][y]=1;
                c++;
            }
        return matrix;
    }
```

Comment: Are the two questions related at all? If not you should ask them as 2 separate questions.

Comment: I think they can count as related, as the answer is very similar.

Comment: Do you *need* a copy? If so, are you sure?

Comment: @Pegah - he's asking if, in terms of requirements of your sort function, you need to make a copy - its your choice. If this doesn't make sense, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: @Pegah You should decide if you need a copy or not first.

Comment: @Dave Newton the variable mat should be a new array, which is the modified version of matrix. But I don't want the matrix to be changed when I go to the line after int[][] mat=sort_vec(3,matrix,indexes); It is OK when matrix is changed inside sort_vec. so you think that I should make a copy of matrix before going inside sort_vec?

Comment: @Pegah - in Java, that doesn't make sense.  matrix is a reference, so it will change it outside of the function as well if it is modified within

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java always passes Objects by reference, so if you return a HashMap-Object from a function, the reference will be passed to the hs variable in your example. Passing the HashSet to the constructor of a new HashSet instance will not work. It will create a new HashSet with the same object references as in the original one. If you modify one of these objects, the change will appear on all other reference points, too.

If you want to totally detach the copy, you will need your own method for deep copying because in the [JavaDoc for the clone() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#clone%28%29) it says:

> Returns a shallow copy of this HashSet instance: the elements themselves are not cloned.

The same goes for arrays. Every array is an object, so if you modify an element, it will be modified for all references to this array. To create a deferred copy, use [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: one nit:  java is always pass-by-value.  In the case of objects, its the value of the reference.  There is a subtle distinction. http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding how Java's references work.

In the first part, your object will be a reference to a HashMap - i.e., whatever object you've returned from the function

In the second part, you are passing a reference to an int[][], it is not pass by value when it's an array of primitives.  Thus, your function will modify the array.  If you want a function that does not modify the input array, you need to copy what is passed in to the function or you will need to copy the array before you pass it to your function.

The behavior in Java sorting routines is that they modify the original array.

In sum, **there is no way to 'pass by value' an object or array in Java**.  If you want this behavior, you have to clone (e.g., copy) the object manually or using @user3001's suggestion

Once you figure this out, you may want to read this as well: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: so you think I should define an array of type Integer instead of primitive type?

Comment: No. Hold up.  That won't matter. Do you want the function to return a copied array that doesn't affect the original?

Comment: the variable mat should be a new array, which is the modified version of matrix. But I don't want the matrix to be changed when I go to the line after int[][] mat=sort_vec(3,matrix,indexes); It is OK when matrix is changed inside sort_vec.

Comment: See my edits, you need to copy the input array and work on that instead of the input

Comment: thank you very much for your time. I got it. I was always thinking that every thing is pass by value. thanks again.