# Take a snapshot of a Set

Tags: java, collections, set

I have Set with items, and want to send it for parallel processing.

However, I want to modify the original set afterwards and it'd cause some concurrency issues, so I think it'd be nice to take a snapshot or something of the Set and send THAt for the processing.

Will `clone` work good?
Or should I make a new `Set` of it myself?
Or is there some nice way I'm missing?

---

*Edit:* I'm now using this, it seems to work pretty nice:

```
public class BufferedHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {

    private List<E> toAdd = new LinkedList<E>();
    private List<Object> toRemove = new LinkedList<Object>();

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e)
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            toAdd.add(e);

            return true;
        }
    }       

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object e)
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            toRemove.add(e);

            return true;
        }
    }       

    public void flush()
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (E e : toAdd) {
                super.add(e);
            }

            for (Object e : toRemove) {
                super.remove(e);
            }

            toAdd.clear();
            toRemove.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `newSet = new LinkedHashSet(setToCopy)`

Comment: clone, will create only shallow copy. I guess what you are looking for is a deep copy. you could  addAll()

Comment: I don't mind if the elements are modified, as long as the set itself stays intact. So clone is good for it?

Comment: Using a [persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) representation of the set, you can avoid the copy. Not sure if it's worth the effort for your case.

Comment: Better not use clone. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10289746/660408

Comment: @gkiko then how to do it?

Comment: @MightyPork isn't _user3374972_'s answer working?

Comment: Sure it is, but I don't like it very much. Actually, I've made a better solution which I'll post in a minute.

Comment: I remember `clone` doesn't really 'copy' the object, it just returns the pointer to the original object. Another way is to write your own deep copy. I think there won't be much difference in time and the memory usage will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the most elegant solution is to use `Set.addAll()` method.

```
Set set;
Set snapshot = new TreeSet<>(); //or any Set implementation you use
snapshot.addAll(set);
```

Comment: why not just the Set(Collection) constructor?